# What is your preferred boolean pair: 1/0 Yes/No True/False?

Tags: sql, naming-conventions, project-planning

1. When dealing with MySQL, I typically use the BOOLEAN type, which is equivalent to TINYINT(1), or 1/0
2. In most languages I work with, true/false is preferred
3. When displaying forms, sometimes "Yes / No" makes more sense

Answer (score 30):

```
enum Bool 
{ 
    True, 
    False, 
    FileNotFound 
};
```

http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx

Answer (score 9):

In code:  true/false.

In the UI: Yes/No or OK/Cancel

Comment: Always check the question you're asking before going with Yes/No or OK/Cancel.  "Do you wish to Cancel the operation?" -- Ok/Cancel

Answer (score 6):

Which is easier to read?

```
while(true) {}
while(yes) {}
while(1) {}
```

I'll stick with true for most cases.

Answer (score 6):

`true` and `false` makes a lot more sense to me, in code - partly through familiarity, I'm sure. I suspect I'd get used to `yes` and `no` pretty quickly. 1 and 0 really doesn't work for me though.

Consider the expression

```
age == 5
```

It's a test for truth-hood. Is the value of `age` 5? Yes, it's true. Both "yes" and "no" would be fine for me, but the idea that the answer to the question "Is the value of `age` 5?" is "1" seems pretty counter-intuitive to me. Just because that's the typical binary representation of truth-hood doesn't mean it's a useful one at a higher abstraction.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention the abstraction bit of this.  BTW, nice podcast on .NET rocks :)

Answer (score 5):

Here are rules I live by...

### Rule #1

Use well defined constants in the programming languages that you use to communicate with the CPU, i.e., true/false in most modern cases for boolean values.  If a database offers a boolean type or some such equivalent, of course it should be used.

### Rule #2

Interact with users of your software by using their preferred language and idiom, i.e., Yes/No questions should offer Yes/No (or perhaps an alternative to No, such as Cancel).

### Rule #3

Uncertainty should be expressed in terms of scope, i.e., "that depends", which will be followed up by the question "on what?".  I know developers who answer the question by copying and pasting just about every dependency they may need into every code file of a project as a 'using' statement. That's just sloppy, and please bother to alphabetize or at least group namespaces together.

### When a bool Just Isn't Enough

Incidentally, an interesting twist to this, available in C#, is Nullable;

The you can write

```
Nullable<bool> RespondToIritatingQuestion()
{
    return new Nullable<bool>();

}
```

OR

```
bool? RespondToIritatingQuestionWithSytle()
{
    return new bool?();

}
```

and the questioner would need to evaluate your response before even knowing what the answer, if there is one, might be...

```
bool? answer = RespondToIritatingQuestionWithStyle();

if (answer.HasValue)
    Trace.WriteLine("The bloke responded with " + answer.Value.ToString());
else
    Trace.WriteLine("The bloke responded with 'depends'.");
```

Comment: Lame, for the record, I did not vote this question down, so, seriously, whoever voted me down should reconsider.

Comment: Isn't that what (!answer.HasValue) means, basically?

Answer (score 2):

1 or 0 for SQL. SQL has a boolean type for a reason. Also, in very large databases, it can effect performance.

Answer (score 0):

I use booleans for true/false fields in databases.  Some people use `ENUM('true', 'false')`, but thats not my preference.  For programming languages, I always use true/false, even if setting it to 0 or 1 will work. And if the form requires 'yes'/'no', I still use booleans to represent the values, but display them as strings that are more logical.